# When exactly should we use rem units in css?

Tags: css, web

From whatever information I have attained from the internet it is clear that rem units are used for specifying the font-size. Where else apart from font-size can we use this unit and what is the browser support for it. 
Is it ok to use rem's for height?

Comment: Sure it's ok but why would you? That's the pertinent question. The reason rem is used for font size is because font size is one of those things where document-wide consistency is often desired. If your layout requires such consistency for certain widths and heights, then there's nothing stopping you from using rems for those either. You just have to think about the reasoning.

Comment: You can use it everywhere you would use any other unit; it’s the same as `em` but according to the root. Browser support is [IE9+ with caveats until IE11](https://caniuse.com/#feat=rem).

Answer (score 1):

> when you want use nested elements and you want font-size Measured than The root element font-size.

See this Example and compare them.

```css
.em {
    font-size: 0.5em;
}

.rem {
    font-size: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<p>When use Em Unit </p> 
<div class="em">I am Div1
   <div class="em">I am Div2
      <div class="em">I am Div3</div>
   </div>
</div>
<p>When use REM Unit </p> 
<div class="rem">I am Div1
   <div class="rem">I am Div2
      <div class="rem">I am Div3</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

> em unit Measure font-size than current font-size that Cause font-size be Smaller and smaller, but rem unit Measure font-size than root Element font-size.